# getting a specific value from JSON array with multiple arrays inside in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm asking here as I can see this website the most one can help in this
I have an output value in JASON format as the following:

```
{
  "total": 16,
  "members": [{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Blade11",
        "descriptors": {
          "os": "Windows 2012 / WS2012 R2"
        },
        "FCPaths": [{
          "wwn": "50060B0000C27208",
          "hostSpeed": 0
        }, {
          "wwn": "50060B0000C2720A",
          "hostSpeed": 0
        }],
        "iSCSIPaths": [],
        "persona": 11,
        "links": [{
          "href": "https://3par:8080/api/v1/hostpersonas?query=\"wsapiAssignedId EQ 11\"",
          "rel": "personaInfo"
        }],
        "initiatorChapEnabled": false,
        "targetChapEnabled": false
      }, {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Blade4",
        "descriptors": {
          "os": "VMware (ESXi)"
        },
        "FCPaths": [{
          "wwn": "50060B0000C27216",
          "hostSpeed": 0
        }, {
          "wwn": "50060B0000C27214",
          "hostSpeed": 0
        }],
        "iSCSIPaths": [],
        "persona": 8,
        "links": [{
          "href": "https://3par:8080/api/v1/hostpersonas?query=\"wsapiAssignedId EQ 8\"",
          "rel": "personaInfo"
        }],
        "initiatorChapEnabled": false,
        "targetChapEnabled": false
      }
```

what I want is, to parse this output for retrieving an output parameter with the name object only in a list or array of string
for example Names =  Blade11, Blade4,....

if you can see in the Json output we have all the names under "members", then each one is another array of values, I want to retrieve only names

thanks

Comment: var names = json.members.map(function(obj){return obj.name});

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have JSON format, you can use an array method on the member key of your JSON object to iterate through each array item.

```
   var names = []; 
   object_name.members.forEach((arrItem) => { 
     names.push(arrItem.name);
   }
```

or

```
  namesArray = object_name.members.map((arrItem) => {
    return arrItem.name;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for iterating all elements of the array and return only the name property.

If you have a [JSON](http://json.org/) string, you need to parse it in advance for getting an object, like

```
object = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

```js
var jsonString = '{"total":16,"members":[{"id":4,"name":"Blade11","descriptors":{"os":"Windows 2012 / WS2012 R2"},"FCPaths":[{"wwn":"50060B0000C27208","hostSpeed":0},{"wwn":"50060B0000C2720A","hostSpeed":0}],"iSCSIPaths":[],"persona":11,"links":[{"href":"https://3par:8080/api/v1/hostpersonas?query=\\"wsapiAssignedId EQ 11\\"","rel":"personaInfo"}],"initiatorChapEnabled":false,"targetChapEnabled":false},{"id":6,"name":"Blade4","descriptors":{"os":"VMware (ESXi)"},"FCPaths":[{"wwn":"50060B0000C27216","hostSpeed":0},{"wwn":"50060B0000C27214","hostSpeed":0}],"iSCSIPaths":[],"persona":8,"links":[{"href":"https://3par:8080/api/v1/hostpersonas?query=\\"wsapiAssignedId EQ 8\\"","rel":"personaInfo"}],"initiatorChapEnabled":false,"targetChapEnabled":false}]}',
    object = JSON.parse(jsonString),
    array = object.members.map(function (a) { return a.name; });

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this JSON is string first you have to parse it

```
var json = JSON.parse('here is your JSON string');
```

Than you can access to it properties like you work with object

```
var names = json.members.map(function(member) {
    return member.name;
});
```